# UBUNTU 16.04 dual monitor not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have a lenovo W520 with a nividia quadro 1000M graphic card with Ubuntu 16.04. I have an extra HP monitor connected to a lenovo mini dock via a DVI cable. When I want to use this extra monitor the resolution is very bad, my mouse clicks on an other location than that I click. Furthermore, it seems as if the screen on my monitor is stretched as if the resolution on my additional monitor is not 1920x1200 but the 3520x1200 (the resolution of my additional monitor together with my laptop screen's resolution). Does anybody know how to solve this problem. Tried updating my drivers and tried different drivers provided by ubuntu but nothing seems to work.

However, adding another monitor seems to solve part of the problem. On both additional monitors  the image is as it should be, the screen of my laptop is black but still showing the mouse.

Comment: are you use the nvidia drivers? the nouveau drivers can't handle multiple monitors well, you should always use the proprietary drivers from nvidia

Comment: using the " NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)" it does not detect the additional monitor.
using the "NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.102 from nvidia-340 (proprietary)" the thing happens as mentioned in the question. The same holds for the driver "NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39 from nvidia-375 (proprietary)." No other " proprietary drivers available @Fl.pf.

Comment: hm, nvidia-340 should normaly not make any problems. Have you `purged` everything nvidia and/or nouveau before installing a new driver?

Comment: I purged everthing from nvidia, installed the nvidia-340 again. But this did not solve the problem. @Fl.pf.

Comment: could you add the info of your Display settings? Picture or complete list

Comment: Additional screen (HP Compaq LA2405wg), Resolution: 1920x1200 (16:10), rotation: normal, scale: 1, launcher placement: hewlett Packard 24" , sticky edges: off.

laptop screen: Resolution 1600x900 (16:9), rotation: normal, scale: 1. @Fl.pf.

Comment: Or is this not what you meant @Fl.pf.

Comment: yeah, more or less. I've been trying to reconstruct your problem on my ubuntu machine last night, but haven't been lucky so far. Next guess would be the mini dock is making problems. Have you tried connecting the external screen directly to the laptop?